# "ld: unknown/unsupported architecture name for: -arch i686" error when installing gcc-4.0.1 on a mac with Darwin 12.1.0

Tags: macos, gcc, linker, gcc4

I am trying to install gcc-4.0.1 on a mac with Darwin 12.1.0 . I did the configuration with `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-4.0.1 --enable-languages=c,c++` . It gives me the following error message when I run make.

```
...
ln -s libgcc_s.1.0.dylib ./libgcc_s.dylib
ld: unknown/unsupported architecture name for: -arch i686
/usr/bin/libtool: internal link edit command failed
make[2]: *** [libgcc_s.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libgcc.a] Error 2
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

I have searched quite a while online, but I couldn't find a solution that works well. If you encountered similar situations before or have any suggestions, please leave a response below. Thanks in advance!

Comment: building gcc on osx is a tough proposition, perhaps try macports